# Display an email from a ConversationID

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to display an email base from an ConversationID

```
Sub displayEmail()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Msg As Object

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set Msg = OutlookNamespace.GetItemFromID("2A744DEFCE5C054F81AB5B960E02AC9A")
Msg.Display
End Sub
```

I am getting an error in this sentence: `OutlookNamespace.GetItemFromID("2A744DEFCE5C054F81AB5B960E02AC9A")`

[image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Hi mathieu! I have a Run-Time error '

Comment: ...I figured as much. Does the error come with any message or number?

Comment: Yes -2147220991.. Thanks for the hint! I need to create that subroutine in Outlook instead of MS Excel

Comment: Not familiar with the Outlook object model, but per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) `Outlook.Namespace.GetItemFromID` takes an optional second parameter for the `EntryIDStore` - try getting the inbox folder, and passing its [StoreID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.storeid) as the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I t could be that you are running into the following issue, explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/189618/you-may-receive-the-run-time-error-2147023174-800706ba-error-message-o). Essentially, you should use a context manager for the Outlook objects you are referencing, so they are released when you don't need them anymore. This allows you to repeateadly execute your code without issues.

```
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

With OutlookApp
    Set OutlookNamespace = .GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    With OutlookNamespace
        Set Msg = OutlookNamespace.GetItemFromID("2A744DEFCE5C054F81AB5B960E02AC9A")
        Msg.Display
    End With
End With
OutlookApp.Quit
```